# Load HTML file contents into element

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Im trying to build a menu that dynamically changes the content of a div with the id of "main-content".

I've got to the point where i've got my switch statement working, and the correct case is being called based on the link clicked, but it's not updating the innerHTML with the new content.

```
let currentUrl;
const content = document.getElementById('main-content');
const logo = document.getElementById('header-logo');

const links = document.getElementsByClassName('side-menu__sub-menu__item-link');
const domain = '$*cdn';
const pagesDir = 'views/styleguide/pages';
const link = `${domain}/${pagesDir}`;
const pages = {
    "Typography": {
        "title": 'Typography',
        "link": `${link}/typography.html`,
    },
    "ColorPalette": {
        "title": 'Color Palette',
        "link": `${link}/colorPalette.html`,
    },
    "Home": {
        "title": 'Home',
        "link": `${link}/home.html`,
    }
}

async function fetchHtmlAsText(url) {
    return await (await fetch(url)).text();
}

async function LoadPage(href) {
    switch(href) {
        case pages.Typography.title:
            console.log("page loaded ", href, "type");
            content.innerHTML = await fetchHtmlAsText(pages.Typography.link);
            break;
        case pages.ColorPalette.title:
            console.log("page loaded ", href, "color");
            content.innerHTML = await fetchHtmlAsText(pages.ColorPalette.link);
            break;
        default:
            content.innerHTML = await fetchHtmlAsText(pages.Home.link);
            break;
    };
}

for (let link = 0; link < links.length; link += 1) {
    links[link].addEventListener('click', () => {
        const parent = links[link].parentElement.parentElement;
        let href;

        // check if parent element exists and if it does get the
        // value of the href attribute
        if (parent) {
            href = parent.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
        }

        // Check if link matches the current page
        if (currentUrl !== href) {
            LoadPage(href);
        }
    });
}


logo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    LoadPage('');
});
```

sidemenu.html

```
<div id="side-menu" class="side-menu">
    <div id="hamburger" class="side-menu__hamburger">
        <div id="side-menu__hamburger__line-01" class="side-menu__hamburger__line side-menu__hamburger__line__01"></div>
        <div id="side-menu__hamburger__line-02" class="side-menu__hamburger__line side-menu__hamburger__line__02"></div>
        <div id="side-menu__hamburger__line-03" class="side-menu__hamburger__line side-menu__hamburger__line__03"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="side-menu__sub-menu">
        <a class="side-menu__sub-menu__item-link" href="#colorPalette">
            <li class="side-menu__sub-menu__item">
                <span class="side-menu__sub-menu__item__icon-container">
                    <i class="fas fa-paint-brush side-menu__sub-menu__item__icon-container__icon"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="side-menu__sub-menu__item__text">
                    Colour Palettes
                </span>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a class="side-menu__sub-menu__item-link" href="#typography">
            <li class="side-menu__sub-menu__item">
                <span class="side-menu__sub-menu__item__icon-container">
                    <i class="fas fa-text side-menu__sub-menu__item__icon-container__icon"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="side-menu__sub-menu__item__text">
                    Typopgraphy
                </span>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you re-rendering the html when the values are updated??

Comment: not at the moment

Comment: You're passing in the `href` attribute to the `LoadPage` function, which I assume is a link/href. but your switch/case statement is comparing it against the titles, ie. `case pages.Typography.title`

Comment: @MarkHughes88 when you are fetching/updating the html elements, they should re render the DOM in order to affect.

Comment: the href is the location of the file. i should probably change the nomenclature there. But yes, the switch statement is working off the title, and updating the link (href) to the file to display based on that title

Comment: how do i re-render the dom element? I usually work in react and that does it for you lol

Comment: Can you post the HTML to make that clearer? The event listeners clearly show that you are passing the value of some element's `href` attribute to the `LoadPage` function, which would generally be a link.

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen i have posted it. that actually helped me find the issue, it was a syntax error! other than that it works how i expected it to! no reload needed